# Find a basis for $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given the subspaces $\mathbb{S}= (1, 2, 1, 1), \mathbb{H_1}= \left\{x \in  \mathbb{R^4} /x_1 − x_2 − x_3 + 2x_4 = 0\right\}$ and $\mathbb{H_2}= \left\{x \in \mathbb{R^4} /−2x_1 + x_2 − x_3 + x_4 = 0\right\}$. Find a basis for $\mathbb{R^4}$ that contains a basis for $\mathbb{S}$, a basis for
>   $\mathbb{H_1}$ and a basis for $\mathbb{H_2}$ simultaneously.

I can take $v_1 = (1, 2, 1, 1)$ as one of the vectors for the basis, and I know that I need 3 other vectores linearly independent to $v_1$, but I don't know how to find them. I tried using $H_1\cap H_2$ but I got stuck. Any hints?

Comment: $\mathbb{S}$ is a single vector, not a subspace.

Comment: It will likely the span of these 4 vectors: (1) the tangent to both planes (H1 and H2), (2) another vector that then spans H1, (3) a similar other vector that, along with (1), spans H2, and (4) S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $\mathbb{S}$ is the subspace spanned by $S=(1,2,1,1)$.

In the intersection of the two hyperplanes, $\mathbb{H}_1 \cap \mathbb{H}_2$, we have

$$\begin{align*} x_1-x_2-x_3+2x_4 & = 0 \\ -2x_1+x_2-x_3+x_4 & = 0 \\ \end{align*}$$

Hence, we have the $2 \times 4$ matrix

$$A = \pmatrix{1 & -1 & -1 & 2 \\ -2 & 1 & -1 & 1}$$

Now, $\mathbb{H}_1 \cap \mathbb{H}_2$ is precisely the null space of $A$. Thus, we will need to find a basis for this null space. Some elementary row operations give us

$$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 2 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 & -5}$$

From this, we obtain

$$V=\pmatrix{-2\\-3\\1\\0}, \ \ W=\pmatrix{3\\5\\0\\1}$$

as a basis for the null space of $A$. Note that $V+W=S$. Therefore, $V$ and $S$ span $\mathbb{H}_1 \cap \mathbb{H}_2$, so we can let these be two of our vectors.

Now we just need to find a vector in each hyperplane which is not in their intersection. From $x_1-x_2-x_3+2x_4=0$ and $-2x_1+x_2-x_3+x_4=0$, we obtain, respectively,

$$X=\pmatrix{-2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1}, \ \ Y=\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2}$$

You can check that $X,Y,V,$ and $S$ are independent. Hence we can choose $X,Y,V,$ and $S$ as our basis. In this case, $S$ spans $\mathbb{S}$, $S$, $V$, and $X$ span $\mathbb{H}_1$, and $S$, $V$, and $Y$ span $\mathbb{H}_2$.